# Finding the value of $c$ that makes this system of equations have a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the value of $c$ that makes the system of equations below have a solution.
>   $$\begin{align*}
> u + v + 2w &= 2 \\ 
> 2u + 3v - w &= 5  \\
> 3u + 4v + w &= c
> \end{align*}$$

I have taken a suggestion from a similar question asked 2 months ago.  After row reduction, I have:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  \hphantom{-}2 & 2  \\
0 & 1 & -3 & 1  \\
0 & 0 &  \hphantom{-}1 & (3-c)/2
\end{bmatrix}$$
From here I am confused on how to actually solve for $c$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please check your row reduction. I think that the 2nd row should be $0, 1, -5, 1$ (2nd row - twice of 1st row)

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. You can also [take a look here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3a9cd16b-5e64-473d-9092-a342903c1d7a/view-source) at how I edited your question.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Calvin.

Comment: Once you correct your row reduction (and also remember to check the third row), you will get the answer. You should get $c=6$ as the answer.

Comment: Calvin~ i got c=7.  from the corrections and in the last row reduction that i did:  -1-(6-c)

Comment: @Lanae: $7$ looks great as Steve answered below and he visually saw it - check out his nice answer.

Comment: @Lance Yes, should be 7 (I made a calculation mistake too!). I'm glad that you were able to get it from row reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the left hand sides of the first two equations gives the left hand side of the third equation, so $c=7$ is the only possibility.

Comment: If i substitute c=7 in the system and solve the system, shouldn't i get right side = left side in the end?

Comment: @Lanea notice the first two equations sum to give you $3u+4v+w=7$ while our third equation is $3u+4v+w=c$. If we want there to be any solution at all it is required that every equation is satisfied and so it follows readily that $c=7$.

Comment: @oldrinb~  I hadn't noticed that!  Thank you!  I'm wondering if the prof wants us to solve for u, v, and w after plugging in c=7.  I tried and it didn't work out.  Most likely because of what you just pointed out.

Comment: @Lanae this system has more than one solution!